# ListView onItemClick confusion

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter, onitemclick

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and I can't find any help online.  Basically I just need to have an onItemClickListener for the items.  All they will do is start a new intent to a new activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyAppActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ListView list1;
private String Cats[] = { "Hardware", "Commands", "Libraries","Tutorials", "Arduino License"};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in
    // list.
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cats);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: And if you are referring to a question related to Android, don't forget to add the Android tag to your question. I have seen this in both the questions you have asked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In string list[] put down the names of your classes you want to appear on the list:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String list[] = {"(names of classes)"};


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try{
    String classlist = list[position];
    Class myclass = Class.forName("(project name)" + classlist);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this,myclass);
    startActivity(intent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  Is this to be another class that I refer to in my onCreate of my main activity?

Comment: Yes it needs to be another class, just put the names in the string list[]. No referring needed.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused.  For the ListView parameter o the onListItemClick, I put the listview name list1, althoug for the view, position, and id parameter i'm confused.  I put Hardware.java for the myclass statement

Comment: Sorry you werent clear enough, please rephrase your question.

Comment: referring back to my code, what would I put for the method call of onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)

Comment: You dont have to put anything, if it doesnt work put @Override before onListItemClick.

Comment: Hm, that didn't make it work.  My first activity doesn't extend ListActivity, if that has anything to do with it.  Wouldn't I need some sort of reference to the Main.class in my first activity?

Comment: Yup thats the problem! Try doing list1.setOnListItemClicklistener(this); and then implement it into the class and add unimplemented methods.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help! I just have a few more questions.  I added the line and implemented the method    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }     Do I need to add anything in there?  I've added everything you've had me add and it still runs it just doesn't start a new intent. So at least it isn't crashing anymore :)

Comment: Have you added the targetted class to the manifest? I dont see any other reason why it should fail.

Comment: Oh wow! how did I forget that!  I've added the class to the manifest.  I'm confused on the line Class myclass = Class.forName("(project name)" + classlist);  For the project name, would I put my first activty or quite literally the project name?  This is my last question, then I'll leave you alone :)

Comment: Haha okay, so you're a newbie. Its okay to mention it in your post, it just gives the answerer an idea about how simplified his answer should be :). Two things, when I say String list[] = {"(names of classes)"}; I mean {"1st class on the list", "2nd", "3rd"}; and  second when I say Class myclass = Class.forName("(project name)" + classlist); I mean YOUR project name for example : ("com.example.yourproject"); Hope thats simplified enough, if not feel free to contact me anytime :)

Comment: Okay so I did that and it isn't doing the new intent.  Its still stable though.  Could you please take a look at my code?  Here is the link to the code http://funkyguy4000.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/my-code-so-far/   THE PASSWORD IS stack

Comment: In your code I cant see anything inside the onlistitemclick, anyway use my code except that dont write classname.java write only the class name because Class.forname function automatically creates it into a classname. If it doesnt work, check your intent filter in manifest (for the DEFAULT activities, not the LAUNCHER one). Inside their name tag write "ANYNAME" and then in your list class do this: Intent intent = new Intent("ANYNAME"); hope this works.

Comment: Mmkay. The code in the onListitemclick method in the class you gave me, I have : super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try{
    String classlist = list[position];
    Class myclass = Class.forName("strutz.electronic.industries" + classlist);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this,myclass);
    startActivity(intent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}       Am I supposed to have something in the implemented classes of my first activity?  In the onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) method?